# Moving informations from file into ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

When I try to move data from textfile into arraylist I get error on  line data.add(row); (no suitable method found) how can I solve it ? Is using arraylist good idea if I want to use it to populate java jtable(swing) ?

```
 public ArrayList<String> getinformationforthetable() {
    Scanner s = null;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        if (line.startsWith("")) {
            String[] atoms = line.split("[#]");
            ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
            row.add(atoms[0]);
            row.add(atoms[1]);
                    row.add(atoms[2]);
                    row.add(atoms[3]);
                    row.add(atoms[4]);
                    row.add(atoms[5]);
            data.add(row);

        }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    finally {
        if (s != null) {
        s.close();
        }
    }
    return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add the List values as String. It wont allow to add. List having the default method as [**addAll()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to add the list values into the mainList

```
data.add(row);
```

instead of

```
data.addAll(row);
```

Answer (score 5):

This error is due to the fact that your data array list is an Array list of strings

```
  ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and you are trying to add another array list to it. you should change it to

```
  List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`data` is decalred as expecting `String` values, but your are adding an `ArrayList` of `String`s to it...

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
//...
ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add(row);
```

Depending on what you want to achieve and based on the example code, you should do something more like...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

If you want to be able to add the `row` `ArrayList` to the `data` `ArrayList`...